# Determining the distance between the top of the page and the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, how do I determine the height/distance between the very top of the browser window to the bottom of a div, such as a header. I'm using the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $totalHeight = $(window).height();
    $headerHeight = $('header').height();
    $('#portfolio-info').css('height',($totalHeight - $headerHeight - 105) + 'px');
});
```

And I want to make sure that `$headerHeight` isn't always the same value, as you scroll away from the header it should decrease all the way down to zero.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the HTML as well? In particular I'm wondering what is the positioning of the div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work out for you.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
        bottomDiv = $('div').offset().top + $('div')[0].offsetHeight,
        distance = Math.max(0, (top - bottomDiv) * -1);
});
```

Comment: If I do this within a $(window).scroll(function()  it sort of works as the user scrolls.....but how do I make sure it stops as 0, rather than having a negative value?

Comment: @JoelEckroth Look at the updated version, I added Math.max so if the number is negative it will return 0 instead.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me if I refresh my page whilst I'm part way down the page. Do you how to get around this?

Comment: @TomHart Duplicate these lines and change the `.resize` to `.load`.